# How to check if cell in variable row is blank, return script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to have my script return if column 11 (K) of the active row is blank.

Here is what I'm using:

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const saveSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = saveSheet.getActiveRange();
  const editrow = range.getRow();

  const activeCell = saveSheet.getRange(editrow,12);
```

I want to run this script

```
  {
    s.toast('Please ensure all data is entered correctly.')
    return
  }
```

So far I have tried the following without success:

```
if(activeCell.isBlank())
if(activeCell == isBlank())
if(activeCell == '')
if(activeCell == null)
if(activeCell.getValue().length > 0)
```

TIA

Comment: Reread your question do you want to know if row or blank or if column is blank.  It's hard to tell your question and amplifying text don't seem to agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check whether column "K" of the same row with the active range is blank.
- When the cell is blank, you want to run `s.toast('Please ensure all data is entered correctly.')`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

I think that in the case of `const activeCell = saveSheet.getRange(editrow,12);`, column "L" of the same row with the active range is checked. In this case, I think that `const activeCell = saveSheet.getRange(editrow,12);` is required to be modified to `const activeCell = saveSheet.getRange(editrow, 11);`.

By the way, when your showing script is used, `s.toast('Please ensure all data is entered correctly.')` might be required to be modified to `ss.toast('Please ensure all data is entered correctly.')`.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function isActiveRowBlank() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const saveSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = saveSheet.getActiveRange();
  const editrow = range.getRow();

  const activeCell = saveSheet.getRange(editrow, 11);
  if (activeCell.isBlank()) {
    ss.toast('Please ensure all data is entered correctly.');
    return;
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, column "K" of the same row with the active range is blank, `ss.toast('Please ensure all data is entered correctly.')` is run.
- If you want to run this script when the cell is not blank, please modify `if (activeCell.isBlank()) {` to `if (!activeCell.isBlank()) {`.
- In this modification, it supposes that the active range has only one cell.
- If you want to check multiple cells in the active range, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function isActiveRowBlank() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const saveSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const range = saveSheet.getActiveRange();
    const editrow = range.getRow();

    const activeCell = saveSheet.getRange(editrow, 11, range.getNumRows());
    if (activeCell.isBlank()) {
      ss.toast('Please ensure all data is entered correctly.');
      return;
    }
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isActiveRowBlank() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();
  const r = rg.getRow();
  Logger.log(sh.getRange(r,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).isBlank()?"Row is Blank":"Row is not Blank");
  return sh.getRange(r,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).isBlank()?"Row is Blank":"Row is not Blank";
}
```